# Linux Mint 19.1 cannot connect to one specific wifi

Tags: linux-mint

I recently updated to Linux Mint 19.1. Since the update I haven't been able to connect to one specific Wifi, all others work fine (Mobile hotspot, etc.). I don't get any error messages, the laptop just doesn't connect. Any help would be greatly appreciated!